# How to replace a html string in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

I have the below html code:

```
<td colspan="2" class="logo_padding">
   <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="80%">
       <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
                <a class="logo" href="mysite.com/"><img src="http://mysite/images_mysite/logo.gif" alt="" title="" border="0"></a>
            </td>
          </tr>                     
      </tbody>
   </table>
```

I don't have control over the html so I need to change the img to jpg to test how it looks :

so I want to replace this string

```
   http://mysite/images_mysite/logo.gif with this : http://mysite/images_mysite/logo.jpg
```

Comment: And where are you stuck? Post your attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without further information:

```
$('a.logo img').attr('src', function(_, src ) {
    return src.replace(/\.gif$/, '.jpg');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the `attribute ends with selector` and the receiver function of `.attr()` to accomplish your task,

```
$('img[src$=".gif"]').attr('src',function(i,val){
  return val.substring(0,val.lastIndexOf('.')) + ".jpg";
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/ujb8T/)

Answer (score 0):

You should catch the image, and change its `src` property

```
$(".logo_padding a.logo img").prop("src", "http://mysite/images_mysite/logo.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$('.logo img').each(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    $(this).attr("src", src.replace(/\.gif$/i, ".jpg"));
});
```